# create simple api with python to catch post request

Tags: api, python-3.x, request, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have developed a python plugin which is capable of sending log file in json format
in mm code i have used `requests.post(url, data={})`

what will be the api structure that catch this `data` and will be available for
send anywhere with `GET` request

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you are trying to do? It sounds like you want to set up a web server that will accept your log file data via POST requests. I don't understand "catch this `data` and will be available for send anywhere with GET request". Where would the final location of your data be? Database? .txt files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fairly new to web programming I would suggest using a lightweight framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). With it you can define custom paths that your server accepts requests on as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

log_file = None

@app.route("/api/logfile", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post_logfile():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if log_file is not None:
            return "Log file not instantiated yet", 404
        else:
            return jsonify(log_file)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        log_file = request.form
        if log_file is not None: 
            # log_file variable will have all the information
            # from the JSON log file
            return "Ok" 
        else:
            return "No data provided", 400

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=9000)
```

As you can see, we have a global variable *log_file* which will be used to store the JSON logfile data, and a function that accepts both POST and GET requests and acts accordingly. If a GET request is sent, it checks if *log_file* variable is assigned. If so, it returns the log file as a JSON file else it return a 404 error. If a POST request is sent it checks if it has the log file and stores in the *log_file* variable, making it useful for all subsequent GET requests.

The URL used are:

> localhost:9000/api/logfile

And you only need to change the method of the request(e.g. POST or GET)

Comment: if i want to use django rest framework  then what can i do.. thanks for flask structure...

Comment: I've never got into Django too much but I guess this tutorial will get you through http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/. Judging from the code though, I think you should first understand how Django works(Models, URLs, Views, etc) in order to use this framework. Good thing is, the internet is full of material to get you started

Comment: i want to receive json data through `request`